# How to prove inequality related to intercausal inference

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Events E and N can cause event G and are independent. How do I prove the inequality $P(E|G) < P(E|G\wedge N)$ using Bayes theorem and probability axioms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't true in general.  Suppose that events E and N are each a toss of a fair coin.
If both E and N are heads, suppose that G is automatically W meaning "you win the game."  If E and N are both tails, then you win the game with probability Y, while if E and N are different from one another then you win the game with probability X.  In this situation, if $Y>X^2$, you have
$$P(E=H|(G=W) \wedge\ (N=H))>P(E=H|G=W)$$ while if $Y<X^2$ this inequality is reversed.

In a little more detail, 
$$
P(E=H|G=W)=\frac{P(G=W|E=H)P(E=H)}{P(G=W)}=\frac{1+X}{1+Y+2X}
$$
and
$$
P(E=H|G=W,N=H)=\frac{P(G=W,E=H,N=H)}{P(G=W,N=H)}=\frac{P(E=H,N=H)}{P(G=W,N=H)}=\frac{1}{1+X}
$$
So the inequality we're looking at is

$$
\frac{1+X}{1+Y+2X}<\frac{1}{1+X}
$$
or $X^2<Y$.